# Insert into table at specific column with unique id

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to Table T1 and T2

T1

```
Id name open receive close
1  jon  5000    0   5000
2  jim  6000    0   6000
```

T2

```
Id name receive
1  jon   5000
2  jim   7000
```

I Want like this Result

```
Id name  open   receive close
1  jon   5000   5000    10000
2  jim   6000   7000    13000
```

I'm using Sqlite

Comment: Hi Muhammad! When asking for help here, please show us what you've already done. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
update t1 set receive=(select t2.receive from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)
```